# java.util.log , using 3 different logger instances/log files, getting .1 .2 etc

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out why I'm generating multiple versions of my log files (.1, .2 ,etc). My project has a need for 3 separate loggers, I'm using java.util.log and setting up my loggers as follows:

```
logger = Logger.getLogger("Logger");
logger.addHandler(new FileHandler(logFileName));
statsLogger  = Logger.getLogger("StatsLogger");
statsLogger.addHandler(new FileHandler(statsLogFileName));
alarmLogger  = Logger.getLogger("AlarmLogger");
alarmLogger.addHandler(new FileHandler(alarmLogFileName));
```

my logging properties file:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=com.package.LogFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=com.package.LogFormatter
```

This seems to work, well as far as I can tell anyway... things seem to be getting logged to the correct log files. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FileHandler javadoc 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler

> Normally the "%u" unique field is set to 0. However, if the
>   FileHandler tries to open the filename and finds the file is currently
>   in use by another process it will increment the unique number field
>   and try again. This will be repeated until FileHandler finds a file
>   name that is not currently in use. If there is a conflict and no "%u"
>   field has been specified, it will be added at the end of the filename
>   after a dot. (This will be after any automatically added generation
>   number.)

Have you got multiple processes running that are using the same log configuration ? Also check that any old test processes are not showing up in windows process viewer or top.